# Print 2 values from a return() without adding

Tags: java, return-value

I having a small problem with this entry of a Math program I am doing.
I have this code on my main.

```
case 15:
    DescendingOrder dorder =  new DescendingOrder();
    System.out.println("Insert the first value: ");
    num10 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Insert the second value: ");
    num11 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Descending Order: " + dorder.decorder(num10, num11));
    break;
```

This is the code I am using on my other class

```
public class DescendingOrder
{
    public double decorder (double num10, double num11)
    {
        if (num10 > num11) {
            return(double) num10  + num11;
        } else {
            return(double) num11 + num10;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, program is printing `num10 + num11` instead of showing `num10` and `num11`.

Is there a way to print the result like:

```
Descending order: num10 num11
```

Ex. I enter 10 and 20. It should return:

```
Descending order: 20 10
```

Instead it shows:

```
Descending order: 30
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: youre returning a double value. you can either return a string from the function, or an ordered collection to be formatted on the main function

Comment: @Zephyr just added more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print a String not a number, so change decorder() to this:

```
public String decorder (double num10, double num11){
    if (num10 > num11){
        return num10 + " " + num11;
    }else{
        return num11 + " " + num10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. "String cannot be converted to double". Thats the error I get.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array containing the two values:

```
public class DescendingOrder {
    public double[] decorder (double num10, double num11){
        if (num10 > num11){
            return new double[] { num10, num11 };
        }else{
            return new double[] {num11, num10 };
        }
    }       
}
```

And then call `Arrays.toString` and pass the return value:

```
System.out.println("Descending Order: " + Arrays.toString(dorder.decorder(num10, num11)));
```

And it will print something like:

```
Descending Order: [2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but Im having an error on the Println - "cannot find symbol" and points to Arrays

Comment: You need to `import java.util.Arrays;` @lordvader

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @lordvader If you think an answer answered your question, please consider accepting it!

Answer (score 0):

Regards,

You are sum the numbers, have many ways to do this, for example:

```
public class DescendingOrder {
public String decorder (double num10, double num11){
    if (num10 > num11){
        return num10  + "," + num11;
    }else{
        return num11 + "," + num10;
    }
}       
}
```

or to:

```
System.out.prinln(num10 > num11 ? (num10 + "," + num11) : (num11 + "," + num10));
```